# Air Circulation inside waterproof IP67 enclosure

Tags: waterproof, ip67

We are using an SHT15 sensor + Arduino to measure relative humidity. The electronics is supposed to operate in a very high Relative humidity (~ 70 - 80) and wet conditions. To protect the electronics we have placed it inside an IP67 enclosure.

However if we seal the box with sensor inside then we are not measuring the humidity of environment. Also, there will be pressure buildup inside the box. we need some kind of vent / membrane filter that will let sensors do accurate measurements by allowing air circulation yet protect the circuit from moisture and dirt damage.

Any idea on how this is done in Industry?

Comment: I am not in this industry, but I'd put the sensor outside the enclosure. Conformal coatings are often used to safeguard against condensation. Dave Jones and Mikeselectricstuff talk about that in some of their videos.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check these vents made by [Gore](http://www.gore.com/en_xx/products/venting/index.html). We have used them in the past for outdoors applications.